# checkcolumn grid cell border conditional change in accordance to disable-enable state in sencha 6.0.2

Tags: extjs

I have a grid with two checkcolumns (apart from the rest columns) and I want to make conditional change of cell (adding specific CSS: making thicker borders of this cell if checkcolumn is enabled and default look if it is disabled) in accordance to disable / enable state.

Unfortunately with using Renderer function I end up with strange outcome (displayed object text or true/false values) because of override native Renderer of checkcolumn I presume. Overwriting checkcolumn renderer is also bad practice which I'm not allowed to do.

I've also tried to use listeners like beforeactivate, beforeDisable etc but they seems not being called whenever state of cell change (disabled <> enabled). I thing that it is possible that its because of using specific bind property as seen bellow.

Is there any method to do it clear (without to much of code repetition and without overriding and adding new method to checkcolumn renderer)??

here is code for one of two checkcolumns in my grid:

```
{
localized: {    
    text: 
'details.tabview.coordination.icccoordination.changepositions.main.view.ebv'
    },
    dataIndex: 'ebv',
    width: 50,
    bind: {
        disabled: '{!changeContextEditMode.active}'
    },
    sortable: true,
    filter: true,
    xtype: 'checkcolumn',
    listeners: {
    beforecheckchange: 'checkIfCheckChangePossible'
    }
}
```

I will appreciate any help

Comment: Ok I've solve it using listeners:disable: 'updateCheckColumnCls', enable: 'updateCheckColumnCls'  and as a parameter is sent checkcolumn. So in method we just need to change tdCls as we want it in my case was check if we are in edit mode and if yes     checkcolumn.tdCls = "valign-middle x-selectable bmw-grid-column-editable" if not     checkcolumn.tdCls = "valign-middle"